# Electron command failed: npm prune --production

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

Trying to build Windows package from Electron using the below command:

`electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon
.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string
.ProductName=\"Electron Tutorial App\"`

It is giving me the below error:

```
Command failed: npm prune --production
npm ERR! May not delete: C:\Users\jessica\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-ia32\Tutorial-win32-ia32\resources\app
\node_modules\.bin

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jessica\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-11T06_51_09_755Z-debug.log
```

I am on Angular 2. NPM version is: 5.3.0.

My package.json is below:

`{
  "productName": "invoice",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "electron": "^1.7.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "electron-packager": "8.1.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

As this user suggest here: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/issues/686

You should run

> npm update -g npm

Then you can build your app again. It worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion the PATH is not correctly configured.
the easiest thing to do is to use the "cmd node" if you are on Windows